# How to translate the search block title?

Tags: 8, blocks, search

In Drupal 8.1.1 I am able to translate customs block and basic blocks (block type).

The search block seems not to be translatable. But I need to translate the title of the standard search block. I can not find a way to do it. Words like "Search" are translated in all languages but the search block title gets not translated.

Answer (score 4):

This is configuration translation. You have to enable the module with this name and then go to block layout, configure a block and click on the tab "Translate block":

```
/admin/structure/block/manage/mytheme_search/translate
```

Comment: This link does not exist.

Comment: ".. but the search block title gets not translated" . Try it out!

Comment: I tried it, it works. To see the result you have to check "Display title".